# Dynamic programming over interval

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I'm working on an algorithms problem, and I'm hitting a wall in speeding it up.

I have a function `f(i,j)`, where `i` and `j` are integers such that `1 <= i <= j <= n` for some upper bound `n`. This function is already written.

Furthermore, this function satisfies the equality `f(i, j) + f(j, k) = f(i, k)`.

I need to compute `f(x, y)` for many different pairs `x, y`. Assume `n` is big enough that storing `f(x,y)` for every possible pair `x,y` will take up too much space.

Is there a known algorithm for this type of question? The one I'm using right now memoizes `f` and tries to reduce `x,y` to a previously computed pair of numbers by using the equality mentioned above, but my guess is that I'm not reducing in a smart way, and it's costing me time.

Edit: Assume that `f(i, j)` takes time proportional to `j-i` when computed the naive way.

Comment: What is the desired space-time trade-off?

Comment: I can do `O(log n)` time and `O(n)` space

Comment: The `O(1)` time and `O(n^2)` space is trivial, as you say

Comment: @UmNyobe based on the identity above, `f(i,i)=0`

Comment: `O(log n)` and `O(n)` space is fine. Does that include the upfront cost of any initialization being done?

Comment: @JanDvorak indeed nice observation.

Comment: OK, is `O(log n)` time, `O(n)` space and `O(n)` preparation time okay?

Comment: actually `f(i,i) = 0`, `f(i,j) = - f(j, i)`

Comment: @Titandrake Can you state your Function more specifically or Can I assume that can be something like F(i,j)=L(j)-L(i) .??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an implicit tree of power-of-two-sized intervals:

- Store `f(i,i+1)` for every `i`
- Store `f(i,i+2)` for every even `i`
- Store `f(i,i+4)` for every `i` divisible by four
- ...

There will be `O(log n)` tables (`floor(log_2(n))`, to be exact), with a total size of `O(n)` (~`2*n`).

To retrieve `f(i,j)` where `i<=j`:

- find the highest bit where `i`, `j` differ.
- Let `n` be the value with this bit set, and all lower bits cleared. This guarantees the following steps will always succeed:
- find `f(i, n)` by cutting off a chunk as large as possible from the right repeatedly
- find `f(n, j)` by cutting off a chunk as large as possible from the left repeatedly

The retreival accesses each table at most twice, and thus runs in `O(log n)`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this solution has a setup time complexity of `O(n log n)`, since the evaluation of `f(i, j)` takes `O(i - j)` time.

Comment: This can be fixed by computing the `f(i,i+2^n)` table by referring to the `f(i,i+2^(n-1))` table. `f(i,i+2^n) = f(i, i+2^(n-1)) + f(i + 2^(n-1), i+2^n)`. Computing each entry takes constant time when done this way.

Answer (score 2):

The function satisfies the rule

```
f(i, j) + f(j, k) = f(i, k)
```

As you say .

So modify the function to something like f(i,j) =g(j)-g(i) , where g(i)= f(1,x)

So as

```
f(i,k)=g(k)-g(i)
      =g(k)-g(j)+g(j)-g(i)
      =f(j,k) + f(i,j)
```

So i think if you try to store all combinations of f(i,j) it is it cost you around o(n^2) space , so better you store value of g(i) values for all values of i which is of o(n) space

so when ever you need to find f(i,j) you can actually find it as g(j)-g(i) .

As

```
  f(i,j)= g(j)-g(i) // as we already calculated and stored the g(i) .
```

Comment: I think the OP does not want us to assume anything on the underlying function `f`

Comment: This solution works if we define `g(x) = f(1, x)`. Then `f(i, j) = g(j) - g(i)`, and the solution takes `O(n)` space, `O(n)` prep time, and `O(1)` time

Comment: `f(j)` is undefined. f, by definition, is a function on `IxI` not `I`. I think you may want to use a different function (if it's even possible)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that requires **`O(n)` space, `O(n^2)` setup time and `O(1)` time per evaluation**.

We have that `f(i, j) = -f(j, i)` for `i <= j`.

Given is `f(i, k) = f(i, j) + f(j, k)`. Therefore, `f(i, k) = f(i, j) + f(j, k) = -f(j, i) + f(j, k)`. In a setup phase, fix `j = 1` arbitrarily. Then, compute `f(1, i)` for every `i` and store the result. This takes `O(n)` space and `O(n^2)` time: `n` evaluations with running times of `1, 2, 3, ..., n`.

For a query `f(i, k)`, we need two constant-time lookups for `f(i, 1)` and `f(k, 1)`.